# MySQL query remove rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that this is not the perfect question for SO but this question is very important for me:

```
DELETE FROM `pligg_links` WHERE `link_id` > 10000
```

Will this query delete all entries in table `pligg_links` which have `link_id`'s bigger than 10000?

Comment: Have you tried to run this line to see what happens?

Comment: no because it needs to do exactly as indicated above other wise ...

Comment: @Chriswede Are you trying to test above query on production directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not sure then run a `SELECT` first to see what will be deleted:

```
SELECT * FROM `pligg_links` WHERE `link_id` > 10000
```

The rows that are returned by this query are those that will be deleted by changing `SELECT *` to `DELETE`.

I would recommend using this technique any time you are writing a `DELETE` statement to prevent accidents due to typos, and especially so if recovering accidentally deleted data is time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you got the propper rights, it will.

Comment: It will also fire any ON DELETE CASCADE foreign keys and delete triggers that might be defined.

Answer (score 1):

If `link_id` is, indeed, an numerical field, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

Always try destructive statements on a backup copy of the database before using it on production. That's assuming you have a copy of the database somewhere.